# Как подать на вход RNN фичи, представленные списком векторов (эквивалентно предложению), а не одним вектором (эквивалентно слову)?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

Как подать на вход RNN фичи, представленные списком векторов(эквивалентно предложению), а не одним вектором(эквивалентно слову)?

Сейчас я для каждого слова в предложении вычисляю векторное представление(word2vec), домножаю на TF-IDF и
усредняю, получается один вектор фиксированной размерности. А хочется подавать на вход не среднее, а последовательность.

```
# Сейчас модель такая - 2 фичи - 2 вектора размерности 300 на входе
r_model = Sequential()
r_model.add(LSTM(200, input_shape=(2, 300), return_sequences=True))
r_model.add(LSTM(300, return_sequences=True))
...
```

Я хочу дополнять списки векторов слов нулевыми векторами до длины максимального - 105. А потом подать такую последовательность на вход:

```
# Хочется подавать на вход последовательность
# max_len - максимальная длина списка векторов
max_len = 105
r_model = Sequential()
r_model.add(LSTM(200, input_shape(2, max_len, 300), return_sequences=True))
r_model.add(LSTM(300, return_sequences=True))
...
```

Но keras говорит, что требуется шэйп размерностью 3, а не 4, как во втором случае:

```
Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_5: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

Answer (score 2):

Любая нейронная сеть, в том числе рекуррентная, ожидает в качестве входа объект фиксированной размерности (и в качестве выхода тоже выдает объект фиксированной размерности).

1. Чтобы подавать на вход именно последовательность и получать на выходе последовательность, можно проходить по данным (в вашем случае - тексту) скользящим окном фиксированного размера, или, если данных меньше, добивать нулями каким-либо образом до нужной размерности.
2. Еще один метод, который можно использовать - объединять векторные представления в одну структуру фиксированной длины, которая будет вести себя как [фильтр Блума](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%91%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0).

   Насколько я знаю, такой прием применяется в хемоинформатике [для быстрого поиска молекул с нужными свойствами](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3124593/) и должен быть  применим к быстрому поиску текстов: в случае с молекулой "словом", которое выражается с помощью вектора, будет фармакофорный фрагмент, а текстом - вся молекула (если Вам интересно понять, что это такое, и составить свое мнение о корректности этой аналогии, то про фармакофоры можно почитать, например, [на geektimes](https://geektimes.ru/post/271758/)).

   Но в качестве входа для нейросети фильтр Блума может давать не очень хороший результат из-за ложноположительных срабатываний, и принципиально этот метод будет похож на тот, который сейчас используете Вы, при этом он не будет учитывать веса слов в тексте. Поэтому я думаю, что Вам больше подойдет использовать скользящее окно.

Comment: Так я и хочу нулями добивать. У меня в коде есть `max_len = 105`, я подразумевал, что дополню все остальные последовательности слов. Но keras ругается на такой shape. Сейчас обновлю вопрос. Все равно спасибо, было интересно почитать про фильтр Блума.